# People search is not working

Tags: search

I followed the directions in this *link and the while the "all sites" search is working, the "people" search is not working.  Do I need to configure a content source (nothing seems to make sense: sharepoint sites, web sites, file shares, exchange public folders, line of business data, custom repository)?  Under the search central admin  > service application > View Scopes, the "people" section items column indicate 0 but the "all sites" items column indicate 243.

*link: http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-enterprise-search-sharepoint-2010/

Is getting people search really this hard out of the box?  I didn't configure the installation, maybe there is a piece missing?

Answer (score 3):

To get ppl search to work make sure that you have successfully provisioned and started

- Managed Metadata
- Search
- User Profile Application

(I also prefer that order for some reason)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure and use sps3://mysite.com in your content source to pick up the people results.